# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/avro/LogicalType while reading Parquet

Tags: java, avro, parquet

I'm trying to read a parquet file, with this simple code:

```java
  ParquetReader<GenericRecord> reader = AvroParquetReader.<GenericRecord>builder(path).build());
  GenericRecord record = reader.read();
```

But getting NoClassDefFoundError for org.apache.avro.LogicalType. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

my version in pom.xml:

```xml
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.parquet</groupId>
      <artifactId>parquet-avro</artifactId>
      <version>1.10.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

full stack trace

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/avro/LogicalType
    at org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroRecordConverter.<clinit>(AvroRecordConverter.java:840)
    at org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroRecordMaterializer.<init>(AvroRecordMaterializer.java:33)
    at org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroReadSupport.prepareForRead(AvroReadSupport.java:138)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader.initialize(InternalParquetRecordReader.java:183)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetReader.initReader(ParquetReader.java:156)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetReader.read(ParquetReader.java:135)
    at cz.seznam.robot.calc.scrank.fulltext.io.ParquetFulltextConverterTest.test(ParquetFulltextConverterTest.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.rules.ExternalResource$1.evaluate(ExternalResource.java:48)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.avro.LogicalType
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 32 more
```

Comment: Which class is'nt found? The exception should say which one.

Comment: it was in the title, added to question too

Answer (score 2):

Ohghg...I had wrong versions of avro, working is this combination

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.parquet</groupId>
   <artifactId>parquet-avro</artifactId>
   <version>1.10.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
    <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.0</version>
</dependency>
```